# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/camera/core/impl/utils/AspectRatioUtil$CompareAspectRatiosByDistanceToTargetRatio;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, zxing, noclassdeffounderror

I'm making a QrCode Scanner app.

Whenever I open my app it crashes and gives NoClassDefFoundError

I checked the logcat and found this:-

```
2023-01-02 08:53:29.552 27370-27370/com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner, PID: 27370
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/camera/core/impl/utils/AspectRatioUtil$CompareAspectRatiosByDistanceToTargetRatio;
    at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SupportedSurfaceCombination.getSupportedOutputSizes(SupportedSurfaceCombination.java:468)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SupportedSurfaceCombination.getSuggestedResolutions(SupportedSurfaceCombination.java:240)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getSuggestedResolutions(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:197)
    at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:431)
    at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.addUseCases(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:239)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCamera.bind(LifecycleCamera.java:206)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCameraRepository.bindToLifecycleCamera(LifecycleCameraRepository.java:283)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:538)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:363)
    at com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner.HomeScreenKt$Scanner$1$2.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:79)
    at com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner.HomeScreenKt$Scanner$1$2.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:60)
    at androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.ViewFactoryHolder.setFactory(AndroidView.android.kt:174)
    at androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView_androidKt$AndroidView$1.invoke(AndroidView.android.kt:116)
    at androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView_androidKt$AndroidView$1.invoke(AndroidView.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView_androidKt$AndroidView$$inlined$ComposeNode$1.invoke(Composables.kt:254)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$createNode$2.invoke(Composer.kt:1537)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$createNode$2.invoke(Composer.kt:1535)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$recordInsert$2.invoke(Composer.kt:3395)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$recordInsert$2.invoke(Composer.kt:3392)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:782)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:813)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:827)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1015)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1102)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18359)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1773)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
```

2023-01-02 08:53:29.556 27370-27370/com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7211)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1004)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:816)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:751)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.AspectRatioUtil$CompareAspectRatiosByDistanceToTargetRatio" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner-Bpfcr28b32Uq7ZGMUq2TGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner-Bpfcr28b32Uq7ZGMUq2TGQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner-Bpfcr28b32Uq7ZGMUq2TGQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 53 more

and the error showing on **AndroidView()** and try{ **cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle**}

```
AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                val previewView = PreviewView(context)
                val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build()
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution(Size(previewView.width, previewView.height))
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build()
                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                    QrCodeAnalyser { result ->
                        code = result
                    }
                )
                try {
                    cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner,
                        selector,
                        preview,
                        imageAnalysis
                    )
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                previewView

            }, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

I also get that error when using this dependency

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha02"
```

it turns out I have to equate all versions, to 1.2.0. After that everything worked

Comment: Still Same Issue
`
AdroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cheesypc.qrcodescanner, PID: 21809
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/camera/core/impl/utils/AspectRatioUtil$CompareAspectRatiosByDistanceToTargetRatio; `

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, you must take into account that all the libraries are in the same stable version, the last one that the documentation indicates is 1.2.0, as you can see in the following image:

[image: camerax versions]

So in the gradle you should define the dependencies as follows:

```
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.0")
```